# How to install Process Editor for TFS?

Tags: windows, team-foundation-server

Task: edit existing template for Work Item in TFS. I've found manual http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668982.aspx, Step 1 – Install Process Editor:

> Install DSL Tools for Visual Studio 2005 before you run the Power Tool installer. This is a prerequisite for the Team System Process Editor. If you do not install DSL Tools, the Power Tool installer installs everything except the Process Editor. The DSL Tools download is available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=82410
>   Download the Power Tool from: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7324c3db-658d-441b-8522-689c557d0a79&displaylang=en
>   Run through the default installation, and then verify that the Power Tool has been installed correctly with the Process Editor as follows:
>   Click Start and then click Programs.
>   Click Microsoft Team Foundation Server Power.
>   If the Microsoft Visual Studio Team System Process Editor appears, this means the Process Editor has been installed correctly. If it does not appear, uninstall the Power Tool and then reinstall it according to the correct sequence as specified in the preceding steps.

I've installed "DSL Tools for Visual Studio 2005", I've installed "Power Tool", but in my "Start" menu in "Microsoft Team Foundation Server" folder the "Process Editor" application is absent...

Why? How could I get that application?

Or probably there is another way to edit TFS work items templates?

Thanks!

P.S. We are using VS2008, TFS 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I looked in the wrong place: 'Process Editor' is accessible from Visual Stuido main menu. Guess, I did all in proper way, because this option was not always there :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need the DSL tools that match your VS version, i.e. 2008. If I recall correctly the DSL tools moved to become part of the VS SDK, so you need the Visual Studio 2008 SDK to get the DSL tools.